# Why does Simple_Form for rails generate downcase placeholders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

With

```
<%= f.input :email, required: true, label:false, placeholder: "Email Adress", autofocus: true %>
```

the generated output will be "Email adress" as a placeholder.
Is there a possibility to suppress this downcasing?

Comment: This is correct syntax, and I can not confirm that behaviour - simple form doesn't do anything weird with placeholders (I am using v3.0.2).

Comment: Thats strange.
I'm using 3.0.2, too. First char is always uppercase and the rest is transformed to lowercase.
Only chars like "ÄÜÖ" aren't changed

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake - I am actually using 3.1.0.rc.

Comment: That is interesting. What happens when you insert ```"Email \u0041dress"``` ?

Comment: Result is the same: Email adress

Comment: I'm experiencing the same results with v3.1.0 - I believe the placeholder is being run through the I18n.t() function twice so it's outputting the placeholder as the I18n default of to_s.capitalize.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because you have to wrap extra html attributes in a `input_html` hash if you also pass any non-html attributes to simpleforms `input`.

Try this:

```
<%= f.input :email, required: true, label: false, input_html: { placeholder: "Email Adress", autofocus: true }
```

Comment: Even with input_html I get the same result